# NgPrime animating when row clicked with Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, css-animations, angular-animations

```
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData let-customer="customer">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
        <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}           
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</ng-template>
```

When the user clicks the row, it instantly appears.

```
animations: [
    trigger('rowVisibleState',
      [
        state('true',
          style({
            height: '40px',
            opacity: 1,
            fontSize: '14px',
            display: 'table-row'
          })),

        transition('0 => 1', [
          animate('500ms ease-in', keyframes([
            style({ display: 'table-row', offset: 0 }),
            style({ fontSize: 0, offset: 0 }),
            style({ height: 0, offset: 0 }),
            style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0.0 }),
            style({ height: '40px',fontSize: '14px', display: 'table-row', opacity: 1, offset: 1.0 })
          ]))
        ]),
        state('false',
          style({
            height: '0px',
            opacity: 0,
            display: 'none',
            fontSize: 0
          })),
        transition('1 => 0', [
          animate('500ms ease-out', keyframes([
            style({ opacity: 1, offset: 0 }),
            style({ fontSize: '14px', offset: 0 }),
            style({ height: '40px', offset: 0 }),
            style({ fontSize: 0, height: 1, opacity: 0.5, offset: 0.9}),
            style({ height: '0px', opacity: 1, display: 'none', offset: 1.0 })
          ]))
        ])
      ])
  ]
```

in my HTML,

```
<tr class="row-spacing" [class.ui-state-highlight]="customer === highlighted" (click)="highlightRow(customer)" [pSelectableRow]="customer" [pRowToggler]="customer" [@rowVisibleState]="highlighted">
```

I think I maybe binding it to the animation incorrectly.

The error in the Browser console is

```
ERROR Error: Unexpected synthetic property @rowVisibleState found. Please make sure that:
  - Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
  - There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@rowVisibleState` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you have ensured the two things that the error message is telling you? You might want to show that in your question.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton do you have any suggestions?

Comment: First thing is to verify the two things in the error message, check:
1. "Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application." (this is referring to app.module.ts)
2. "There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@rowVisibleState` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator" (ie. the animation you've declared is in the correct ts file, the one associated with the html you've shown.)
I'd like to assume you've already checked these two things, but with the information you've given it's impossible to tell.

Comment: So it was installed with npm @angular/animations therefore it should automatically add it to the AppModule for me

Comment: Well what should be and what is are two different things... You seriously not gonna check? `npm` doesn't add imports to app.module btw, `ng add` might but `npm i` doesn't.